# Coordinate points overlay not appearing on background map generated in Altair from a geojson file

Tags: python, altair

I’ve successfully plotted lat long coordinates markers using the world map topojson file from the vega_datesets in the exact manner of this example:

https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airports.html

I just wanted to use other custom background maps however.  Following this example:

https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1612#issuecomment-511830524

I was able render a map in Altair from a custom geojson file successfully as well.

The problem comes when trying to plot the same lat lon points on top of the new background map.

Plotting only the background shows the world map fine (example code below) and likewise, the points appear fine when plotted alone.

Plotting background + points yields only the lat lon points on a white background.

The background map is evidently converted to epgs: 4326 projection as preferred by Altair.  Do the lat/lon points need to be generated differently to work with the alternative background map?   I assumed lat lon were simply coordinates that would would work for any projection.

If the background map displays properly for the geojson version, I’m not clear why the same lat lon values no longer will overlay normally.

**The relevant code that does not work:**

```
url= 'https://aeronet.gsfc.nasa.gov/CLIMO_SITE_SUMMARY/world.geo.json'

gdf = gpd.read_file(url)

# set projection and reproject
gdf.crs = {'init' :'epsg:27700'}
gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})

# define inline geojson data object
data_geojson = alt.InlineData(values=gdf.to_json(), 
format=alt.DataFormat(property='features',type='json')) 

background = alt.Chart(data_geojson).mark_geoshape(
# background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
)#.project('equirectangular’)    


# points on background
points = alt.Chart(loc).mark_circle(
    size=30,
    color='steelblue'
).encode(
    longitude='Longitude(decimal_degrees):Q',
    latitude='Latitude(decimal_degrees):Q',
    href='url:N',
    tooltip=['Site_Name']
) 

#chart= background  # this will display map normally    

chart= background + points  # only points on white background
```

**And the prior code that does work with Vega-lite data using the same ‘loc’ data points.**

```
world = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url,feature='countries')  

# World map background
background = alt.Chart(world).mark_geoshape(
# background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
).project('equirectangular')


# aeronet sites on background
points = alt.Chart(loc).mark_circle(
    size=30,
    color='steelblue'
).encode(
    longitude='Longitude(decimal_degrees):Q',
    latitude='Latitude(decimal_degrees):Q',
    href='url:N',
    tooltip=['Site_Name']
)

chart= background + points.  # works as expected
```

I realize that ‘data_geojson’ and ‘world’ are not equivalent types in the above examples but I’m not clear how that difference should be accommodated in Altair.  I have previously tried to convert geojson examples to topojson format and had the same issue however.

Comment: can you provide a subset of the location data you're trying to plot, or some equivalent example data?

Comment: @anant. Yes, the location data are here: 

https://aeronet.gsfc.nasa.gov/aeronet_locations_v3.txt.     

I don’t think the location data are the issue as they are fine with the original example.

Comment: what happens if you use `gdf` directly instead of `data_geojson`? Are you sure the geo data you're using needs to be reformatted?

Comment: Yes, in fact the original non-reformatted file does work properly.  Thank you! I can't say I understand why.  If the re-format I did caused the problem, I'm confused why it still showed the background map without the addition of the location points.  I would have assumed the points still be overlayed on the incorrectly projected map.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the comments: The OP had an issue with the formatting of their geojson file.